# Emacs. Specific formatting autopair for "{"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have found many ways to automatically insert "}" after typing "{" but never found the following implementation:
After typing "{" it moved on the next line (with indented if necessary), next is an empty string with the cursor, and "}" on the next line:

```
if (i == 0)*here we typing "{"*
```

and get the following:

```
if (i == 0)
{
   |
}
```

and for nested brackets:

```
if (i == 0)
{
   if (j == 0)
   {
      |
   }
}
```

How to do this?
Note: I already use yasnipped but it does not work for functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `electric-pair-mode`, you can supply your own function:

```
(defun my-electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs()
  "Indent paired char and empty line"
  (when (and (eq last-command-event ?\n)
             (< (1+ (point-min)) (point) (point-max))
             (eq (save-excursion
                   (skip-chars-backward "\t\s")
                   (char-before (1- (point))))
                 (matching-paren (char-after))))
    (save-excursion
      (insert "\n")
      (indent-according-to-mode))
    (indent-according-to-mode))
  nil)

(setq-default electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs 'my-electric-pair-open-newline-between-pairs)

(electric-pair-mode 1)
```

It will do what you describe only if you hit return between empty brackets.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. Your solution works a little differently. To get the desired result i have to do the following:
/press return before type "{"/
/type "{"/
/press return/
This solution is suited If we exclude the first return.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this to try to emulate Eclipse's newline functionality.

```
(defun my-newline ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((s (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point))))
    (cond
     ((string-match ".*{$" s)   ; matching a line ending with {
      (move-end-of-line nil)
      (insert "}") ; insert }. Can be removed if already being inserted
      (backward-char 2)
      (newline-and-indent)
      (forward-char)
      (newline-and-indent)
      (move-beginning-of-line nil)
      (backward-char 1)
      (newline-and-indent))
     (t (newline-and-indent)))))
```

You can then attach it to whatever keybinding you like. I overrode C-j as that was what I was used to.

```
(defun my-newline-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'my-newline))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-java-hook)
```

The regex and steps taken can be adjusted to fit your needs.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use additional shortcuts in this situation. Perhaps this function can be bound to typing "{".